# ranking documents from my database

Tags: ranking, text-mining

Everytime i seach for papers / documents on document ranking or text classification i am redirected to pages about related to web pages, but i want to rank documents in a repository.

Can someone suggest a book/paper that talks about ranking documents which are present in a database of documents (Every search result returns page rank or someother algorithm pertaining to the internet)

My aim is to rank the documents from my database based on their relevance to a query or based on a user's reference document(No internet or web sites involved)

Comment: Here are some: But I feel these are too complicated and not sure whether they exactly fit your requirment. http://srw.cheshire3.org/contextSets/rel/

Comment: This link sounds more like a documentation. it would be great if i could get hold of some book or paper on this subject. I am not into the implementation part yet. I am still searching for better ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably stick to an existent document ranking library or database. Most SQL databases have a full-text search mechanism. If you are working with text indexing only, you might as well look into many text searching/document ranking solutions, such as Lucene (there are many others around as well).
If you want to understand how ranking algorithms work, it could be worth taking a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity.
If you want to understand how indexing such information to make searching efficient, you should look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index.
Please note, however, that I am no expert on the matter, and many other approaches exist, although they shouldn't be too different in its basic form.
Using a system that does this dirty job for you will not only save you time, but will also give you more robust and reliable querying capabilities then you would be able to implement on your own in a decent amount of time.

Comment: I have read these techniques earlier . The problem is they are pretty oudated . When i search for recent techniques , all of them talk abt text retrievel based on the internet / links an all of that.

Comment: You are probably right that the document similarity techniques I mentioned are outdated (the inverted index is certainly not). As far as modern solutions go, I can't be of any help. If you can't find anything around, perhaps you should take a look into modern implementations and/or ask the developers of these systems to find out how they are doing it.

Comment: i mistook inverted index to inverted document frequency. I am not aware of inverted index. I am looking into it now.